# how to compare two times values?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

In this segment of code the user input two times values, I want to set if the current time is between those two values or out, the user input the hour and the minute value only.

```
    info=tk.Frame(self, bg=BG, highlightbackground='red', highlightthickness=0)
    info.pack(fill='x', ipady=0)
    title=tk.Label(info, text='System Time', font=('verdana', 20, 'bold'), fg=FG, bg=BG, width=20).grid(row=0, columnspan=2)
    blank=tk.Label(info, text='', bg=BG).grid(row=1)

    start_time_entry=tk.Label(info, text='Start Time Entry', bg=BG, fg=FG, font=FONT).grid(row=2)
    start_hour_entry=tk.Entry(info, width=2, font=FONT)
    start_hour_entry.grid(row=2, column=2)
    start_hour_entry.insert(0, '00')
    point=tk.Label(info, text=':', bg=BG, width=1, font=FONT).grid(row=2, column=3)
    start_min_entry=tk.Entry(info, width=2, font=FONT)
    start_min_entry.grid(row=2, column=4)
    start_min_entry.insert(0, '00')
    blank=tk.Label(info, text='', bg=BG).grid(row=3)

    end_hour_entry=tk.Label(info, text='End Time Entry', bg=BG, fg=FG, font=FONT).grid(row=4)
    end_hour_entry=tk.Entry(info, width=2, font=FONT)
    end_hour_entry.grid(row=4, column=2)
    end_hour_entry.insert(0, '00')
    point=tk.Label(info, text=':', bg=BG, font=FONT, width=1).grid(row=4, column=3)
    end_min_entry=tk.Entry(info, width=2, font=FONT)
    end_min_entry.grid(row=4, column=4)
    end_min_entry.insert(0, '00')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it simple and just use python's `datetime` module to get the current hour of the day and minute of the hour and make a comparison with your inputs.  This is easier if you use common units, so my example below converts into minutes of the day.  Get your user inputs and compare to something like this.

The alternative is to use actual datetime objects and build them from strings from your input and compare those to the `datetime.now()` object.

```
In [5]: from datetime import datetime                                           

In [6]: datetime.now().hour                                                     
Out[6]: 21

In [7]: datetime.now().minute                                                   
Out[7]: 32

In [8]: time_in_minutes_of_day = datetime.now().hour*60 + datetime.now().minute 

In [9]: time_in_minutes_of_day                                                  
Out[9]: 1294
```